# Change (or animate) path using jQuery SVG

Tags: javascript, svg, jquery-svg

I created some sample code based on the jQuery SVG plugin that shows a text along a path. Now when I click the text, I would like to change the path (e.g. from [[50,50],[100,100]] to [[50,50],[200,300]]). I'd also like to know how to apply this change using an animation.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.svg.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.svgdom.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      jQuery(function($){
            $('#debugsvg').svg({onLoad: function(svg) {
                var path = svg.createPath();
                var text = svg.text("");
                var defs = svg.defs(); 
                svg.path(defs, path.move(50, 50).line(100, 100),  {id: "myPath"}); 
                svg.textpath(text, '#myPath', "foo bar");
                $(text).click(function(e) {
                    alert("Animate me please!");
                });
            }});
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="debugsvg" style='height="600px", width="600px"'>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I created some code to parse the 'd' attribute of the path and replace this attribute with a new value, see below. Animation appears not to be possible, as only [certain attributes](http://keith-wood.name/svgRef.html%20/%22certain%20attributes%22) can be animated with JQuery SVG.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.svg.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.svgdom.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.svganim.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      jQuery(function($){
            $('#debugsvg').svg({onLoad: function(svg) {
                var path = svg.createPath();
                var text = svg.text("");
                var defs = svg.defs(); 
                var path = svg.path(defs, path.move(50, 50).line(100, 100),  {id: "myPath"}); 
                svg.textpath(text, '#myPath', "foo bar");
                $(text).click(function(e) {
                    var d = $(path).attr('d');
                    var re = new RegExp("([^,]+),([^L]+)L([^,]+),([^,]+)", "");
                    var m = d.match(re);
                    var dNew = m[1] + "," + (m[2] - 20) + "L" + m[3] + "," + (m[4] - 40);
                    $(path).attr({d: dNew});
                });
            }});
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="debugsvg" style='height="600px", width="600px"'>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```